# Create several integers with a formula?

Tags: java

Is there a way to do what the title suggests? What I'm trying to do is create a table of experience values required to level up like so:

```
    int level1 = 50;
    int level2 = level1 + (level1 * 0.1);
    int level3 = level2 + (level2 * 0.1);
```

But I want to get to around 100 levels... Is there a way to quickly define x number of usable int values?

Comment: Use an array instead of a zillion variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're continuing that formula...

```
int[] array = new int[100];
array[0] = 50;
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  array[i] = (int) (array[i - 1] * 1.1);
}
```

Comment: So, inside of an array, each value can be assigned another value similar to HashMaps? So 0 (or level 1) is = 50, then 1 (or level 2) is = 55? Sorry, I'm kinda learning on my own through trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach:

```
public class Level
{
  public Level()
  {
    int[] levels = new int[100]; // 100 Levels

    initializeLevels(levels);
    printLevels(levels);
  }

  private void initializeLevels(int[] levels)
  {
    levels[0] = 50;

    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    {
      levels[i] = (int) (levels[i - 1] * 1.1f);
    }
  }

  private void printLevels(int[] levels)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      System.out.println("Level " + (i + 1) + " = " + levels[i]);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new Level();
  }
}
```